# How to merge two the same objects in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have two objects that look like this:

```
obj1 = { hostname: "test",
         cpu: 20, 
         disk_space: nil,
         ram: nil,
         check_time: "2017-12-05 01:28" }

obj2 = { hostname: "test",
         cpu: nil,
         disk_space: 3000,
         ram: nil, 
         check_time: "2017-12-05 01:28"}
```

I want to overwrite `disk_space: nil` with `disk_space: 3000` from `obj2`. I want to basicaly overwrite `nils`.

```
new_obj = { hostname: "test",
            cpu: 20,
            disk_space: 3000,
            ram: nil,
            check_time: "2017-12-05 01:28" }
```

How can I achieve this in Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`merge`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Hash.html#method-i-merge)?

```
obj1.merge(obj2) { |key, oldval, newval| oldval.nil? ? newval : oldval }
=> {:hostname=>"test", :cpu=>20, :disk_space=>3000, :ram=>nil, :check_time=>"2017-12-05 01:28"}
```

In short:

```
obj1.merge(obj2) { |_, v, w| v.nil? ? w : v }
```

Comment: You are a genius :D Thank you!

Comment: We could use `oldval ||= newval` as well.

Comment: @Sagar, not if `oldval` could be `false`.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer @StefanPochman's answer, but since that approach was taken, here's another.

```
obj1.merge obj2.select { |k,_| obj1[k].nil? }
  #=> {:hostname=>"test", :cpu=>20, :disk_space=>3000, :ram=>nil,
  #    :check_time=>"2017-12-05 01:28"}
```